# How to group sources by pattern in a view in logdna

Tags: logdna

I would like to create a view where sources are added dinamically if they match certain pattern. I know this is possible in papertrail but I'm stuck at setting up the same behaviour with LogDNA. Any idea if this is possible at all?

Comment: this is a basic feature that i'm still not able to get, its hard to find rare errors without this. 

currently, i'm using exclusing search